# nvim-tree: on open, collapse all folders except the current buffer - how?

Tags: neovim

I'm quite used to nerdtree where when you opened it, all the folders would be collapsed except the ones to the current buffer.

At the moment nvim-tree keeps all the ones you've opened open, making things a bit messy.

Comment: I've tried to implement it via events and via new binding, have to delve deeper in nvim-tree help :) they have collapse_all method, but it receives only one option _keep_buffers_ boolean, which implies to keep ALL open buffers not just the current one.